# Find my Phone investigation indicated a portable network?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, find-my-iphone

I noticed my MacBook Pro said it was offline when I signed into find my phone. I was using my MacBook Pro and it was not offline. I don't know what other MacBook Pro would be signed in under my Apple Id. I decided to turn off the offline MacBook Pro to see what would happen. My Mac is right here next to this computer and it is working.

I decided to check out Voice Over on my MacBook Pro and Fred voice said You are currently on a portable network. As I was trying to look up what a portable network is .. then my screen went dark came back on and I could not get it to say I was on a portable network by scrolling over the same area as before.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: What should I do about the fact that turned a MacBook off? It is still off.

Comment: I just needed to sign into icloud with my macbook.